# How to efficiently count the indexes of set bits in a bigint value?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I understand that the Hamming Weight algorithm and popcnt can efficiently count the number of bits set in a value. However is there a similar operation to count the indexes of bits set? for example:

`0010110`

will return 7 (index 1, 2 and 4 set)

to be clear, I'm looking for as low level an implementation as possible.
My aim is to do this for values up to 1024 bits in length.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages, choose one. Then your question is too broad, because efficiency can mean very different things. (number of code lines, number of operations, number of memory accesses...)

Comment: Unclear which value you want: index 1 and 2 would produce 3 as if only index 3 is set ? and index 0 is useless. Are there any usage ?

Comment: @kay, your are already the second to propose this. No they seem to be looking for the sum of the bit positions.

Comment: "I'm looking for as low level an implementation as possible."  In that case, tag it with your platform and asm

Comment: You are not "counting" the indexes, you are summing them.

Comment: Insufficiently specified - type of 'value' not given.  Assuming it's just the seven bits shown in the question, use a 128-byte lookup table.

Comment: Here's a look up table solution https://ideone.com/Sdswvd A 256 entry look-up table is of course an option.

Comment: On the x86 platform i'd unpack the 32(?) = 8x4-bit integer to 8 bytes (e.g 0x7A32F1C1 becomes 0x70A03020F010C01), using SSE instructions. After unpacking you can use the `pshufb` instruction to do a parallel table lookup. A horizontal add gives you the value that you want. So, what is your platform of interest? x86, ARM, PowerPc, MIPS. etc.

Comment: In case the platform is x86: does your cpu support the AVX2 instruction set? With bitstreams of such length (1024), an AVX2 solution with the `pshufb` trick should work quite well.

Comment: For 1024 bit numbers, I would recommend my suggestion with `ByteCount`/`ByteSum` tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76139951/popcount-assembly-sum-indexes-of-set-bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are after a fast implementation, I would recommend to use a lookup-table of 256 entries, giving the desired sum for all possible byte values (as the maximum sum is 28, this will fit in a byte).

Then split your integer in bytes (I don't know how many, you didn't specify) and accumulate the looked-up values.

For a correct total, you will have to adjust for the origin of the indexing on every byte. Two options

- implement separate tables for the different bytes,
- also use a table of bit counts to compute the corrections (8 x byte index x bit count).

.

```
unsigned char Byte0Sum[256]= { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... };
unsigned char Byte1Sum[256]= { 0, 8, 9, 17, 10, 18, 19, 27, ... };
...
unsigned Total= ByteSum0[N & 255] + ByteSum1[(N >> 8) & 255] + ...;
```

or

```
unsigned char ByteCount[256]= { 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, ... };
unsigned char ByteSum[256]= { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, ... };
...
unsigned Total= ByteSum[N & 255] + ByteSum[(N >> 8) & 255] + 8 * ByteCount[(N >> 8) & 255] + ...;
```

Depending on your application, other table sizes can do.

Comment: Shouldn't `8 * popcnt((N >> 8) & 255)` be added to the contribution of the second byte, and so on? (or separate tables, of course)

Comment: @Harold: oops, you are quite right, thanks for pointing, I am updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any [built-in functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html#Other-Builtins) that will do this, so perhaps a simple loop such as the following would be the fastest:

```
unsigned int bit_index_sum(unsigned int n) {
    for (int i=1,s=0; i<sizeof(n)*8; i++) {
        n >>= 1;
        if (n & 1) s += i;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: `i<32` that's assuming that the integer is 32 bits.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre True

Comment: either `sizeof(n)*8` or use `stdint` to fix sizes

Comment: It doesn't make much sense talking about a "fastest" implementation, if you don't specify the architecture.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Good idea :-)

Comment: why not `s += (n & 1);` ? would have to disassemble it to see which is fastest, and of course it depends on the processor.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Read the question again

Comment: You could use `__builtin_ctz` to avoid testing bits and only iterate over the set bits, but that's not great for numbers with lots of 1's

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = whatever;
int i = 0, sum = 0;
while(a){
    if (a & 1){
        sum += i;
    }
    a = a >> 1;
    i++;
}
```

As suggested by the comments this would not work for negative numbers unless you take the absolute value and add the sign to the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good answer, but you might as well initialize `i` to 1 and move the right-shift before the `if` statement.

Comment: Either use `unsigned int` instead of `int`, or explain what will happen if you supply a negative number. Add comments.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of 'value' was not explicitly given in the question, I will assume seven bits, as used in the example given.

Use a 128-byte lookup table and address it directly.  XLAT, or similar.